# Counting grouped records from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

there is a column `comment_id` of a table called `pic_alb_love` which i'd like to add to the query below but i don't know how.  Actually what i want to do is to count the total `comment_id` of the table `pic_alb_love`.

```
SELECT users_pics.wardrobe, 
     profile.fname,
     users_pics.pic,
     users_pics.u_pic_id,
     users_pics.email,
     users_pics.make,
     users_pics.designer,
     photo_comment.comment,
     max_photo_comment.count_pic_id
FROM dbo.users_pics 
INNER JOIN profile 
    ON users_pics.email = profile.email  
LEFT Join (SELECT pic_id
                ,MAX(comment_id) max_comment_id
                ,COUNT(pic_id) count_pic_id
           FROM photo_comment
           GROUP BY pic_id
          ) max_photo_comment 
    On users_pics.u_pic_id = max_photo_comment.pic_id         
LEFT Join photo_comment 
    On max_photo_comment.pic_id = photo_comment.pic_id 
        AND max_photo_comment.max_comment_id = photo_comment.comment_id
WHERE users_pics.wardrobe = MMColParam 
    AND users_pics.email = MMColParam2
ORDER BY u_pic_id asc
```

these are the various fields of the table pic_alb_love:

```
(comment_id,pic,love_com, wardrobe, email
    ,com_name,resp_email, play_count, com_stat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Pic
              ,Count(*) [CommentCount]
           FROM pic_alb_love 
           GROUP BY Pic) c 
    ON c.Pic=u_pic_id
```

Assuming that `pic_alb_love.pic` is the FK on the table...
Use `[CommentCount]` in the select list.

Comment: can you please insert it into mine so i can see the end results. cos i when i add this to mine the result gave me no new column